# Problema com Proxy (corporativo) utilizando o dev_appserver.py - GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Olá,

Estou com um problema na utilização do Google App Engine e gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.

Na minha máquina tenho instalado:

- Windows XP
- Python 2.7.6
- Google App Engine 1.9.17 (é o mais novo)

Fiz uma aplicação exemplo e não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela execute localmente na minha máquina. Pesquisando no Google identifiquei que o problema é o Proxy da empresa. Veja o mesmo problema no artigo https://www.marshut.net/iwuhqp/dev-appserver-py-cannot-connect-to-some-http-endpoint.html

Consigo chamar o dev_appserver.py [aplicação], mas quando acesso http://localhost:8080 o erro é apresentado. Consigo realizar o Deploy (push) para o a nuvem sem erro.

Na minha casa tenho a mesma versão do Python e Google App Engine, somente o Windows que é o Vista. Consigo realizar os meus testes sem erros, tanto ambiente de desenvolvimento quanto o deploy.

Não consigo desabilitar o Proxy na empresa, pois questões da política de segurança.

O que posso fazer para ter o ambiente de desenvolvimento funcional na minha estação de trabalho? Existe algum workaround?

Abraço e obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Podes adicionar o traceback do erro?

Answer (score 0):

O grande problema eh que seu CMD nao esta com proxy ativo, voce precisa levantar o http_proxy dentro do seu CMS:

1. Acesse o **painel de controle** e clique no **Sistemas**
2. Vai em **avancado** (tab), click em **variável de ambiente**
3. Click em **nova**
4. Adicione **http_proxy** com as informacoes do seu proxy

Isso eu achei em um blogpost para Windows XP, segue o link de referencia:
http://kaamka.blogspot.ca/2009/06/httpproxy-environment-variable.html

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio. Realizei as configurações informadas, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.